# Android google map

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

I am try to add Google MAP Api v2 in my application.but I am getting exception. Exception is

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.googlemapsv2/info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class fragment
```

Here is my xml class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my main class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private GoogleMap _googleMap=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try
        {
            //loading map
            initilizeMap();
            _googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

            _googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);       

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void initilizeMap() {
        if(_googleMap==null)
        {
            _googleMap=((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            if (_googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

}
```

this is my logcat

```
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.demo/com.example.demo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.example.demo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  ... 11 more
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.demo-2.apk]
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:544)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
01-31 14:20:55.603: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
```

Comment: Please post your complete code and logcat. Thanks.

Comment: Try to extends FragmentActivity....

Comment: i did.but its give same exception

Comment: post the logcat if you can.

Comment: also post your manifest.xml

Comment: what is your minimum SDK target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `SupportMapFragment` instead of `MapFragment`.

Change

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

to

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Also change

```
   _googleMap=((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

to

```
_googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
        R.id.map)).getMap();
```

And also If you're using fragments on older devices (pre Honeycomb) you should always extend your `Activity` from `FragmentActivity`.

and also check

**Add the Google Play services version to your app's manifest**

> Edit your application's AndroidManifest.xml file, and add the
>   following declaration within the element. This embeds the version of
>   Google Play services that the app was compiled with.

You just need to add `<meta-data>` under `<application>` tag into your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
....<application>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

This is because `latest google play services requires a version name, which is to be mentioned using <meta-data .. /> inside AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Extend your MainActivity from FragmentActivity.

Refer this :

[Inflating Google Maps v2 fragment causes ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848698/inflating-google-maps-v2-fragment-causes-classnotfoundexception)

Answer (score 0):

In your xml try to change from

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

to

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

Check if this work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Fragments your `MainActivity` must extends `FragmentActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    //Stuff
}
```

---

If you are using the Support-Library so you can use your Fragments in lower Android API Levels use This:

```
public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity{
    //Stuff
}
```

And use the SupportFragmentMap in your XML:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```