# Android app using Google Maps API v2 crashes on some devices

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm developing an Android application which is using Google Maps API v2. When I run it on my Sony Xperia P it works fine. I tried to run it on another Xperia P and HTC One X and it works alright. But when I try to run it on different device (so far I've tried with two different devices), it crashes.

Here's the what I get in the LogCat when I try to run the application on a Sony Xperia Tipo:

```
02-23 17:42:57.205: E/AndroidRuntime(829): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 17:42:57.205: E/AndroidRuntime(829): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.java.demo/com.example.android.java.demo.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider==null
02-23 17:42:57.205: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
02-23 17:42:57.205: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
02-23 17:42:57.205: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-23 17:42:57.205: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
02-23 17:42:57.205: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-23 17:42:57.205: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-23 17:42:57.205: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-23 17:42:57.205: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 17:42:57.205: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-23 17:42:57.205: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
02-23 17:42:57.205: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
02-23 17:42:57.205: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-23 17:42:57.205: E/AndroidRuntime(829): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider==null
02-23 17:42:57.205: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.location.LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.java:1046)
02-23 17:42:57.205: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at com.example.android.java.demo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:182)
02-23 17:42:57.205: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
02-23 17:42:57.205: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-23 17:42:57.205: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
02-23 17:42:57.205: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  ... 11 more
```

EDITED: Problem solved. Google Location Services should be enabled.

Comment: Go to this question :[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968077/runtime-exception-unable-to-start-mainactivity/21968279?noredirect=1#comment33288697_21968279](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968077/runtime-exception-unable-to-start-mainactivity/21968279?noredirect=1#comment33288697_21968279)