# Adding Google map to android application

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps

I'm trying to create a map in android. I have the following code and the log cat error message.

My MapSearch.java file:

```
public class MapSearch extends FragmentActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_search);
  }
}
```

My map_search.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/mapsearch"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

the error messages from logcat:

```
02-26 17:09:04.863: E/AndroidRuntime(17436): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-26 17:09:04.863: E/AndroidRuntime(17436): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pir.mobileprivateoffersretrievalV2/com.pir.percyclient.MapSearch}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class fragment
02-26 17:09:04.863: E/AndroidRuntime(17436):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
02-26 17:09:04.863: E/AndroidRuntime(17436):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
02-26 17:09:04.863: E/AndroidRuntime(17436):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-26 17:09:04.863: E/AndroidRuntime(17436):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
02-26 17:09:04.863: E/AndroidRuntime(17436):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-26 17:09:04.863: E/AndroidRuntime(17436):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-26 17:09:04.863: E/AndroidRuntime(17436):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-26 17:09:04.863: E/AndroidRuntime(17436):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 17:09:04.863: E/AndroidRuntime(17436):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-26 17:09:04.863: E/AndroidRuntime(17436):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-26 17:09:04.863: E/AndroidRuntime(17436):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-26 17:09:04.863: E/AndroidRuntime(17436):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-26 17:09:04.863: E/AndroidRuntime(17436): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class fragment
02-26 17:09:04.863: E/AndroidRuntime(17436):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
02-26 17:09:04.863: E/AndroidRuntime(17436):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
02-26 17:09:04.863: E/AndroidRuntime(17436):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
...
```

Comment: try this link..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21475489/android-google-map..

Answer (score 1):

There is no Api Key defined in your android manifest. Your map wont load without that. Second, you didn't define all the permissions in your android manifest. OpenGl, that's also a must. Refer to this code. This will help you..:)

My Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
Button btn1;
EditText et1;
EditText et2;

GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (servicesOK()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.testmap);

    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);

    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean servicesOK() {

    int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

        return true;

    } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {

        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable,
                this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
        dialog.show();

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Cant connect!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    return false;
}
}
```

My Layout:

```
xmlns:maps="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And finally the Android Manifest. This is the most important think you will have to consider:

```
package="com.mike.maps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<permission
    android:name="com.mike.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.mike.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" >
</uses-feature>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.mike.maps.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.mike.maps.SecondActivity" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="Your API KEY goes here" >
    </meta-data>
</application>
```

Hope this helps you..:)

Comment: Iv'e voted u up because I was at the same problem where you were before..:)..Lemme know if this explains..and if yes, accept my answer..;)

Comment: I defined API key in my manifest file & i have OpenGl in manifest file too. I tried to use android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
instead of
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
but still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

to

```
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Reason being you are extending a `FragmentActivity` rather than a `Fragment` and must use a `SupportMapFragment`.