# Showing Error ---java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

When I press the button `btnlocation` it should go to the `Mapsactivity`
 but it is giving me the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

I also added `MapsActivity` in manifest as usual .. .but why this error? I need the solution.Can any one help me please...

```
package com.mamun.tasktest;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;


public class FragmentB extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    private Button btnLocation;
    private LocationManager manager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_b, null, false);

        btnLocation = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnLocation);
        btnLocation.setOnClickListener(this);
        manager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
              AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
              builder.setTitle("GPS is currently disabled");
              builder.setMessage("Please enable GPS for better view of your location.\nWould you like to change these settings now?");
              builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                      startActivity(i);                                                                                                                         
                    }                       
                  });

              builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      getActivity();
                    }
                  });
              builder.create().show();
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            if(isMapAvailalble()){
            /////////////////////////////               
            /* 

            // */                               

            //////////////////////////

                 Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(),MapsActivity.class);
                 startActivity(in);             
        }
        }

        /*Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE"); intent.putExtra("enabled", false);
        sendBroadcast(intent);*/                                
    //if googleplayservis or play store is not available/updated or user recoverable problem occured. 
    public boolean isMapAvailalble()
    {
        // to test if there is no googleplayservise
        //int resultcode=ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING;
        int resultcode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());
        if(ConnectionResult.SUCCESS==resultcode)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultcode))
        {
            Dialog d = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultcode, getActivity(), 1);
            d.show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity()," Google Map API is not supported in your device",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    /*public void turnGPSOn()
    {
         Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
         intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
         ((Context) this.ctx).sendBroadcast(intent);

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(((Context) ctx).getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
            ((Context) this.ctx).sendBroadcast(poke);


        }*/
    }
```

**Manifest.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mamun.tasktest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.mamun.tasktest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-library  android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

    <permission
        android:name="com.mamun.tasktest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" >
    </permission>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.mamun.tasktest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCgGng3iaqbTxJ3B_lYemZBEqXOonUtFEI" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity android:name="MapsActivity"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

***MapsActivity***

```
package com.mamun.tasktest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

public class MapsActivity<GeoPoint, OverlayItem> extends MapActivity implements
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
     MapView mapView;
     com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint p;
    private LocationManager manager;

    private TextView tvAddress;
    private Button btnSearch;
    private EditText etSearch;
    private LocationClient locationClient;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private MapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.map);

        manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        tvAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvaddress);
        btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.maps);
        googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
        locationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

    }

    public void onSearch(View v) {

        // Getting user input location
        String location = etSearch.getText().toString();

        if (location != null && !location.equals("")) {
            new GeocoderTask().execute(location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        locationClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        locationClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        try {

            Location currentLocation = locationClient.getLastLocation();
            double lat = currentLocation.getLatitude();
            double lng = currentLocation.getLongitude();
            // txtLocation.setText(lat + ", " + lng);

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);

            ArrayList<Address> address = (ArrayList<Address>) geocoder
                    .getFromLocation(currentLocation.getLatitude(),
                            currentLocation.getLongitude(), 5);
            Address addr = address.get(0);
            String currentAddress = (addr.getAddressLine(0) + "-"
                    + addr.getAdminArea() + "-" + addr.getLocality() + "-"
                    + addr.getPostalCode() + "-" + addr.getCountryCode());
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
            options.position(new LatLng(lat, lng));
            options.title(currentAddress);
            options.snippet("Current location");
            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
            if (googleMap != null) {
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                        new LatLng(lat, lng), 14.0f));
                googleMap.addMarker(options);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Map is null",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    // An AsyncTask class for accessing the GeoCoding Web Service
    private class GeocoderTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Address>> {

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
            // Creating an instance of Geocoder class
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
            ArrayList<Address> addresses = null;

            try {
                // Getting a maximum of 3 Address that matches the input text
                addresses = (ArrayList<Address>) geocoder.getFromLocationName(
                        locationName[0], 3);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return addresses;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Address> addresses) {

            if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location found",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            // Clears all the existing markers on the map
            googleMap.clear();

            // Adding Markers on Google Map for each matching address
            for (int i = 0; i < addresses.size(); i++) {

                Address address = (Address) addresses.get(i);

                // Creating an instance of GeoPoint, to display in Google Map
                LatLng latLng;
                latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(),
                        address.getLongitude());

                String addressText = String.format(
                        "%s, %s",
                        address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address
                                .getAddressLine(0) : "", address
                                .getCountryName());
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                // markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                markerOptions.title(addressText);

                googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                // Locate the first location
                if (i == 0)
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                            .newLatLng(latLng));
            }
        }
    }




    class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas, com.google.android.maps.MapView mapView,
                boolean shadow) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

            Point screenPts = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e,
                com.google.android.maps.MapView mapView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (e.getAction() == 1) {
                com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint p =  mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
                        (int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
                Toast.makeText(
                        getBaseContext(),
                        "Lat: " +  p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + ", Lon: "
                                +  p.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


}
```

Comment: are you referring any libraries? Please post your logcat.

Comment: Now post your manifest.xml. logcat clearly said you have not added Activity onto manifest.ml

Comment: I posted the manifest too @ M D & Amrut

Comment: <activity
        android:name="com.mamun.tasktest.MapsActivity"
        android:label="MapActivity" >
    </activity>                                                    <activity android:name=".MapsActivity"></activity>  .I followed these two  process but it is not working

Comment: I added the MapsActivity @ M D

Answer (score 1):

Add `Activity` into your `manifest.xml` because you need to give all path if your `Activity` located into different package.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.mamun.tasktest.MapsActivity"
        android:label="MapActivity" >
    </activity>
```

And/or is your `Activity` belong to the same package then add simply

```
<activity android:name=".MapsActivity"></activity>
```

For more information go to:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Comment: I already provided this answer. You should post new answer in case it is something different or adds more value. Else you can just upvote the correct answer.

Comment: @Sushil i already provide something different. look at my answer

Comment: MapsActivity extends MapActivity. If MapsActivity extends Activity it works fine but problem is that I needed to extend MapActivity and that time Application is crashing @M D help me plz

Comment: @user3076959 What?? post your `MapsActivity` then.

Comment: I posted MapsActivity@M D

Comment: @user3076959 here you are used `mapFragment` then you need to extends only `Activity` and for your information i told you `Google Map V1` has deprecated and for more information go to this post:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21475489/android-google-map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21475489/android-google-map)

Comment: @user3076959 your issue is solved then you may accept anyone most useful answer or +1 up vote thnx

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect:

```
 <activity android:name="MapsActivity"></activity>
```

You need to give full or relative path like this:

```
 <activity android:name="com.mamun.tasktest.MapsActivity"></activity>
```

or

```
<activity android:name=".MapsActivity"></activity>
```

Comment: Provide a **links** for user better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your this tag in manifest

```
 <activity android:name="MapsActivity"></activity>
```

by :

```
 <activity android:name=".MapsActivity"></activity>
```

you should specify your full package name while declaring your activity into manifets.

See this link for reference:-
[Add a new activity to the AndroidManifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832619/add-a-new-activity-to-the-androidmanifest)

Comment: I already provided this answer. You should post new answer in case it is something different or adds more value. Else you can just upvote the correct answer.

Comment: @Sushil I've provided something different in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just forget to place a **DOt (.)** before `MapsActivity`. So, without that **Dot (.)** your class path looks like...

```
com.mamun.tasktestMapsActivity.java
```

But, it should be as....

```
com.mamun.tasktest.MapsActivity.java
```

Now, change this line of your `Manifest`...

```
<activity android:name="MapsActivity"></activity>
```

to...

```
<activity android:name=".MapsActivity"></activity>
```

Comment: I already provided this answer. You should post new answer in case it is something different or adds more value. Else you can just upvote the correct answer.

Comment: @Sushil...that doesn't look like something different from your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution....The line "" should be inside application not inside directly on manifest.Like as below....