# Android GoogleMap: change getFragmentManager() to SupportMapFragment() - NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I want the application to run on the version of Android - 8

I found some "answers", but still receives on a NullPointerException.

```
        try {   
            FragmentManager myFM = ActivityMapa.this.getSupportFragmentManager();

            final SupportMapFragment myMAPF = (SupportMapFragment) myFM.findFragmentById(R.id.mapa);
            map = myMAPF.getMap();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("mapa", "FR error: " + e);
            map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapa)).getMap();
        }
```

second answer:

```
// in try()
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapa)).getMap();
```

The code is in:

```
public class ActivityMap extends ActivityOptions {  // ActivityOptions extends FragmentActivity

    (...)
    protected void onCreate() {

        // try()

    }


}
```

What to do to not get an exception?

Comment: Kindly to go this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21475489/android-google-map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21475489/android-google-map)

Comment: Thank You! 
I have not changed android: name = "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" in xml.

Where can I select the solution thread?

Comment: Working on the device

Comment: We did not understand a. App already running, previously missing only the changes in xml file: MapFragment -> SupportMapFragment. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: How to I noted in a post that is solved?

Comment: Yes, in post, but where is option "accept the answer" in comments?

Comment: not in comment it is available only in Answer